# Metrics for evaluating the effectiveness and fairness of local police departments and DA offices

Tags: police

I want to understand how my local police department and DA's office stack up against other municipalities in terms of budget support, effectiveness, fairness, job satisfaction and community satisfaction. I will do some legwork at bjs.gov and vera.org. My knowledge level in this problem area is between 1 and 2 on a scale of 1 (lowest) to 10 (highest).